# In VSTS, how to query for PBI that has no uncompleted child tasks of a particular activity type?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We're using hosted Visual Studio Team Services to track our stories and tasks.  We'd like our testers to be able to query for Product Backlog Items in the current iteration that have no uncompleted child tasks of the development activity type.  I'm having trouble putting such a query together, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a "Work item an direct link" type query and set the Filter option to "Return items that do not match links" and the link type to "Child".

[image]

Filter the Child type further to include any combination of fields you don't want to have. You can use groups and and+or constructs to limit by multiple exclusive conditions.

Comment: That's perfect thanks @jesse.  Is there a way to filter at the same time for a PBI that also has child tasks that meet different crtieria, such as having uncompleted QA tasks?  If it's involved, I can post as a separate question and link it.

Comment: I don't think so. Because that would imply a "has relation" filter and the query above relies on  "doesn't have relation". If you give the total requirement, there may be a way to do it...